# Does a function have Taylor expansion on every point if the function has a Taylor expansion on zero in $(-R,R)$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Maybe the expression of the title is not very clear. My detail thought is following:

There is a function $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined on a interval $I=(-R,R)$. If $f$ has Taylor expansion $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n$ satisfying for all $x\in I$,  is it true that $f$ has Taylor expansion for every point of $I$, which means $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}b_n(x-x_0)^n$ satisfying in sufficient small neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$, where $U\subset I$?

The proposition above is obviously true if $f$ is defined on complex plain, but I am not sure whether it is true on the field of real numbers. Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: You know you can just reinterpret your Taylor expansion as the expansion of a complex function, right?

Comment: To clarify: Not only do all derivatives exist at $0$ to compute $a_n=\frac1{n!}f^{(n)}(0)$; not only does $\sum a_nx^n$ converge in a neighbourhood of $0$; but the limit of the series is also $f(x)$ in such a neighbourhood?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Authur's hint. I think I can prove the proposition.

For any point $x_0\in I$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x_1^n$ is convergence in $I$, where $x_1$ equals $x_0+\delta$ or $x_0-\delta$ depending whose absolute value is larger. Then in complex plain $\mathbb{C}$, the series $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n$ is absolutely convergent in the open disc $D(0,|x_1|)$, and uniformly convergent in any closed disc $\bar{D}(0,k|x_1|)$,$0<k<1$. Defining a function $g(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n z^n$, $|z|<K|x_1|$, where $K$ is a positive constant smaller than $1$ and larger  than $|x_0|/|x_1|$. Therefore, $g(z)$ is analytic in $D(0,K|x_1|)$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ when $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $x_0$ is in the analytic domain of $g$, $g$ has Taylor expansion on $x_0$, then $f$ has Taylor expansion on $x_0$ in real line obviously.